# Haskell Type class using foldr

Tags: list, haskell, types, typeclass

I wrote a function using foldr that determines the length of a list or string. I'm a little confused as to why Haskell determined the type class to be of Num. Surely strings aren't included in this class? However Haskell insists it must be so, or else the function won't work. Could someone help to clarify why this is?

```
myLength' :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int
myLength' xs = foldr (\x acc -> 1 + acc) 0 xs
```

Comment: Which version are you using? GHC 7.10 infers the type of your function to be `(Num b, Foldable t) => t a -> b`.

Comment: GHC 7.8.4 if that helps at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your type signature might have been made too specific by your declaration. Here's what I get in GHCi:

```hs
> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

> :t foldr (\x acc -> acc + 1)
... :: Num b => b -> [a] -> b
```

The `+` is where the `Num` constraint comes from. It only applies to type `b` because `acc`'s type unifies with `b`. No further constraints arise as we're not doing anything with `x :: a`.

```hs
> :t foldr (\x acc -> acc + 1) 0
... :: Num b => [a] -> b
```

`0` easily unifies with `Num b => b` and nothing changes except we drop an arrow.

```hs
> :t \xs -> foldr (\x acc -> acc + 1) 0 xs
... :: Num b => [a] -> b
```

We introduced an argument `xs` with no specific type, which easily unifies with `[a]`. Nothing changes. So our final type should be

```hs
myLength :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
myLength = foldr (\_ acc -> 1 + acc) 0
```

This *does* work on strings. `myLength "hello" => 5` and so on.

As Lee mentioned in the comments, `foldr`'s type changed in GHC 7.10 to `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` as part of the [Foldable Traversable in Prelude Proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710/FTP), which allows `foldr` to be used on many different data structures instead of solely lists. On GHC 7.10 then your function would indeed have a type inference of `myLength :: (Foldable t, Num b) => t a -> b`. Note how `(Foldable t) => t a` generalizes `[a]`.

HOORAY TYPES

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything so clearly and concisely!